# OpenGL. Не рисуется ничего при использовании индексного буфера

Tags: opengl, graphics

Почему у меня не отрисовываются треугольники?

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from ctypes import *

window = pyglet.window.Window()

vertex_data = [
    -1, 1, 0,
    -1, -1, 0,
    1, 1, 0,
    1, -1, 0
]
vertex_data_gl = (GLfloat * len(vertex_data))(*vertex_data)
vbo = GLuint(0)

color_data = [
    0, 0, 255,
    0, 0, 255,
    0, 0, 255,
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0
]
color_data_gl = (GLfloat * len(color_data))(*color_data)
cbo = GLuint(0)

indices = [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
indices_gl = (GLfloat * len(indices))(*indices)
ibo = GLuint(0)

#Активация вершинного буфера
glGenBuffers(1, vbo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertex_data_gl), vertex_data_gl, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)

#Активация буфера цветов
glGenBuffers(1, cbo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(color_data_gl), color_data_gl, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

#Активация буфера индексов
glGenBuffers(1, ibo)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices_gl), indices_gl, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)


#Отрисовка 
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cbo)
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0)

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)

#glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, len(vertex_data_gl))
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, len(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0)

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)

glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: glGetError возращает ошибку или нет?

Comment: @Unick glGetError возвращает только "0" и все

Comment: Какую версию OpenGL вы используете?

Comment: @Unick Версия OpenGL 4.5

Comment: Возможно вы привели не весь код. Насколько я понимаю вы должны установить шейдер для отрисовки.